# Copy data from JTable as HTML

Tags: java, swing, copy, jtable, data-transfer-objects

JTable's default TransferHandler exports data in tab-delimited format. I'm trying to create my own TransferHandler that will export the data as an HTML table, but currently *nothing* gets copied to the clipboard when I use it. How can I add this feature?

Currently I'm adding the following TransferHandler to my table using `table.setTransferHandler(new TableTransferHandler());`:

```
public class TableTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TableTransferHandler");

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent comp) {
        JTable table = (JTable) comp;
        logger.debug("creating table selection transferable");
        return new TableSelection(table);
    }

}
```

`TableSelection` Transferable:

```
public class TableSelection implements Transferable {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TableSelection");

    private static DataFlavor HTML_TEXT;

    private static final List<DataFlavor> flavors = new ArrayList<DataFlavor>();

    private JTable table;

    public TableSelection(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavors.contains(flavor);
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return flavors.toArray(new DataFlavor[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws IOException, UnsupportedFlavorException {
        if (flavor.equals(HTML_TEXT)) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<table>");
            int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
            int[] cols = table.getSelectedColumns();

            for (int row : rows) {
                int col_index = 0;
                sb.append("<tr><td>");
                for (int col : cols) {
                    Object value = table.getValueAt(row, col);
                    if (value != null)
                        sb.append(value.toString());

                    if (col_index + 1 < cols.length)
                        sb.append("</td><td>");
                }
                sb.append("</td></tr>\n");
            }
            sb.append("</table>");

            return sb.toString();
        }
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }

    static {

        try {
            HTML_TEXT = new DataFlavor("text/html;class=java.lang.String");
            flavors.add(HTML_TEXT);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Couldn't create HTML_TEXT flavor", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with nothing gets copied to the clipboard. Is your transferable not created ? And how do you expect this will work. Your transferable contains only one dataflavor, which is private. So how will anybody retrieve the data from your transferable if they do not have access to the flavor ?

Comment: After CTRL+C on the table, I get previously copied text rather than data from the table. I could be going about this all wrong as this is my first attempt to use TransferHandlers.

Comment: I thought the [default handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/swing/1.4/dnd.html#DefaultTransferHandlerSupport) did this, but setting `setDragEnabled(true)` copied plain text.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one piece missing. You need to implement `TransferHandler.getSourceActions`, like so:

```
public class TableTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    ...
    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: this works on Mac OS X. But on Windows, pasting to notepad or wordpad works, but not OpenOffice calc. After some investigation, I think Java AWT and OpenOffice both have fault:

- Java produces following HTML clipboard format:

> Version:0.9 
> StartHTML:-1 
> EndHTML:-1 
> ...

Those two `-1` are wrong. They are supposed to be some positive offset numbers. There is a [know JDK bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6392086) that is very close to what you have here.

- OpenOffice, on the other hand, can't handle such partially correct clipboard format, while notepad or wordpad can. There are [7300+ (!) open bugs](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=&content=paste+html+calc) if you search for 'paste html calc' in OpenOffice bugzilla database.

Comment: Now the logging indicates that my custom Transferable is being used, but when I "paste special" into OpenOffice Calc and select HTML format, it says "the contents of the clipboard could not be pasted". Pasting into Thunderbird or Notepad or jEdit has no effect.

Comment: @bemace works for me. Do you change your code after you posted them here?

Comment: What OS are you using? It's starting to look like windows requires [some special clipboard headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#unknown_156)

Comment: @bemace I use Mac OS X. Does adding those special clipboard headers work for you now?

Comment: It crashes OpenOffice now, so maybe I'm on the right track. Still can't paste into Thunderbird. Notepad displays the raw html including header lines

Comment: @bemace maybe both Java and OpenOffice have fault in this issue. See edited answer.